# How To Identify Cell Address VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How do I find the last line/Row of an edited document meaning new information will be added to the document without my knowledge and I still need to be able to identify its address. VBA

Answer (score 0):

```
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

If you don't need VBA, then press Ctrl + Down Arrow in a column with continuous rows to bring you to the last row